# How to implement 2 checkout in magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to implement TCO and write below code in magento2.

```
$two_checkout_model = Mage::getModel("tco/ins")->load($two_checkout_message_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already many free modules available for implementation of 2checkout in magento2:

**Paid Extension:** https://marketplace.magento.com/magerainbow-twocheckout.html

**Free Extensions:**

- https://github.com/craigchristenson/magento2-2checkout
- https://github.com/mage2pro/2checkout

Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Why did you downvote?

Comment: To promote or suggest any third-party module is not allowed in Magento stackexchange. so please remove your answer or any responsible person will downvote or create flag for your answer.

Comment: @RonakChauhan, This is not the promotion of third-party modules. I have just suggested trying pre-made module to avoid unnecessary reinventing the wheel by writing code for a payment method which is already freely available.

Comment: @RonakChauhan, If you can answer this question in a better way, then please answer before downvoting.

Comment: I haven't downvote your answer, I was just suggest you not to suggest any thirdparty module to anyone because Seniour person can downvote your anser for that reason.